# System Verilog: Check if Signal stays high

Tags: system-verilog, verification

is there a simple way to check if a given signal stays high for a few microseconds. As far as I understood, in SVA we can only check if the signal is high at a certain timestamp.

Comment: SVAs **can** check width it in terms of clock cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this signal is a module port, you can use the `$width` timing check.

```
module desgin(input wire signal);
  specify
    $width(posedge signal, 2us);
  endspecify
  ...
endmodule
```

If this is an arbitrary signal, you can use the `bind` statement to insert this module anywhere in your design

```
module widthcheck #(real limit) (input signal);
  specify
    $width(posedge signal, limit);
  endspecify
endmodule

module testbench;
  bind target_instance widthcheck#(2us) (target_signal);
  ...
endmodule
```

Of course, there is always the brute force approach

```
real rise, fall, width;
always begin
  wait(signal)  rise = $realtime;
  wait(!signal) fall = $realtime;
  width = fall - rise;
  if (width<limit)
     $error("signal width(%t) less than limit(%t)", width, limit);
end
```